# CodeIgniter Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I'm getting the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class News in application\models\Entities\News.php

The two classes are as follow:

`application/models/News_model.php`

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH."models/Entities/News.php");

class News_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

`application/models/Entities/News.php`

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* News
*
* @ORM\Table(name="news", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="slug", columns {"slug"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class News {
}
```

The first class is a model and the last class is entity class for `Doctrine`.

I cannot see which is the conflict whether the two names are different.

I'm using `CodeIgniter 3.1.4`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Take the `require_once` out, you may not need it.

Comment: But I need interact with Entities/News.php, CRUD operations.

Comment: It may already be loaded via CI's autoloader. Which is why it would be trying to declare the class twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 classes with the same name.

The file being included with `require_once` is called News.php, therefor I assume it is a class called News.

Then you also have a News class in Doctrine. There 2 classes are in the same namespace with the same name and php does not allow that. You will either need to look into using namespaces or change the name of one of those 2 classes.

**Note that it is not your model itself in codeigniter but the file being included by using `require once` which is conflicting with your Doctrine `News` class.**

Comment: I have one class called News and other called News_model in different directories.

Comment: namespaces are in context of a php instance and not restricted to directories. Change the name of the News class in `models/Entities' or in doctrine and that error will go away.

Comment: model/Entities/News.php is the doctrine class, there isn't two News.php class

Comment: With namespace a solved the problem. But there weren't two News classes, the model/Entities/News.php is the same Doctrine class, only for clarify.